# Не устанавливается финальная и отладочная версия вместе

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-debug

Хочу иметь на устройстве одну debug-версию приложения и одну release-версию.
В Gradle необходимое прописал:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Но при gradle-sync вылазит ошибка:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.money.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.debug'
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в firebase проекте пакет с *.debug, скачайте новый .json и вложите на уровень /app

Comment: Можно более развернуто? Что за проект firebase? Пакет с *.debug нужно просто добавить или в нем что-то должно быть?

Comment: @Evgeny, в консоли Firebase вам надо добавить приложение андроид, указав там пакет с суффиксом `debug`, т.к. у вас в скрипте сборки он указан. После этого, добавив отпечатки ключей там же, в консоли, в созданном приложении надо скачать google-services.json и поместить его в проект. Возможно дополнительный пакет можно и в уже созданном в консоли приложении добавить. В любом случае вам надо обновить файл google-services.json

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, буду пробовать)